# File Upload In Angular Error 403 Access Denied

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, postman

I create function in angular

```
onFileUpload() {
    this.uploader = new FileUploader
    ({
      url: environment.apiUrl + "/uploadImage"
      , 
      autoUpload: true,

    });
    this.uploader.onCompleteAll = () =>
    this.uploader.onErrorItem = (item, response, status, headers) =>
    this.onErrorItem(item, response, status, headers);
  }
```

but when console
[image]

please help me..
I have tried several methods but the result is still access denied

Comment: check the api through postman and add necessary details in header of request

Comment: what method you are using to upload the image is it base64 or formdata  or urlencoded please check that